# ffplay thinks stream is 5.1(side) and not 5.1

Tags: sound, ffmpeg

When I try to play my 5.1 flac files with ffplay, it automatically detects the stream thusly:

```
  Duration: xx:xx:xx.xx, start: 0.000000, bitrate: xxxx kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), s32 (24 bit)
```

As you can see, it detects the files as having the channel layout 5.1(side).
This makes the side speakers (which should really be rear speakers) very quiet.
If I add gain to those channels, they distort. I just want them to play properly, with the other 5.1 channel layout in the ffplay documentation, described as FL,FR,C,LFE,RL,RR.

Here is an excerpt from the ffplay documentation:

```
Standard channel layout compositions can be specified by using the following identifiers:

‘5.1’

    FL+FR+FC+LFE+BL+BR

‘5.1(side)’

    FL+FR+FC+LFE+SL+SR
```

Both of the above layouts have 6 channels. So how can I specify I want to use '5.1' and not '5.1(side)'?

It’s for this layout the audio was mixed, and it’s this layout that I have set up with speakers.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you were to open the file in mediainfo it likely would report something like Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE  "Side" is now what once was called by some 'back or rear'. Back or Rear is now only in 7.1. Your issue is likely something else.

Comment: In the ffplay documentation, there are two 5.1 setups, 5.1(side) and 5.1. (The latter being described as FL,FR,C,LFE,RL,RR)

Comment: ffplay is totally capable of assigning the layout I mentioned, I just don’t know how to go about it

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard http://www.mediafire.com/file/mcgq1rsgbd1r5k0/voltest.flac/file

Comment: Does `ffplay -af "aresample=out_channel_layout=5.1" -i voltest.flac` work? I'm unable to test as I don't have that many speakers.

Comment: No luck, I'm afraid. It doesn't seem to make any difference at all.

Comment: I think you can test that regardless, since it's not ffplay's problem that you can't organise the output stream into separate speakers. It should still show up as "5.1" or "5.1(side)".

Comment: What do you get with this flac?  `wget https://0x0.st/sWV_.flac`  (your's remapped to BL & BR

Comment: This works! ffplay notes that this uses "5.1" configuration. You should make your method into an answer so you can receive the bounty. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @doug did you receive the response above? Specifically [this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057634/ffplay-thinks-stream-is-5-1side-and-not-5-1#comment1737468_1057634)

Comment: For some reason not notified.. will craft an answer shortly

Comment: @Nectar How about `ffplay -af "channelmap=channel_layout=5.1" voltest.flac`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [channelmap](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelmap) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -af "channelmap=channel_layout=5.1" output.flac
```

Or re-map channels upon playback if you want to avoid re-encoding:

```
ffplay -af "channelmap=channel_layout=5.1" input.flac
mpv --audio-channels=5.1 input.flac
```

Answer (score 3):

What I did was take your 5.1(side) flac file & split into 6 .wav files with ffmpeg (must be relativity recent ffmpeg.

So to start, in an empty folder placed the .flac, then cd'd to that folder in a terminal. This command will split to .wav's. (using voltest.flac as example

`ffmpeg -i ./voltest.flac  -filter_complex "channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1[FL][FR][FC][LFE][SL][SR]" -map "[FL]" front_left.wav -map "[FR]" front_right.wav -map "[FC]" front_center.wav -map "[LFE]" lfe.wav -map "[SL]" back_left.wav -map "[SR]" back_right.wav`

After splitting then re-encoded back to a flac using this command

`ffmpeg -i front_left.wav -i front_right.wav -i front_center.wav -i lfe.wav -i back_left.wav -i back_right.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a]amerge=inputs=6[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.flac`

So output.flac will be mapped as you desired. You could probably create a script to do a number of .flacs at once  back to orig. name with a little experimenting..